# Oracle Apex 5.1 use NVL in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle-apex

I write a PL/SQL in my Apex app.

I want to set `NVL` with Dynamic Parameter. `q` is a string query, `:P53_INS_FIELD` is a Parameter. When I write `NVL`, it makes an error (Failed to parse SQL query).

My code is:

```
q:= q || ' and nvl(' || :P53_INS_FIELD || ' , ifl.id) = ifl.id';
```

This is wrong in Apex. The error is "Failed to parse SQL query"

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

When you write like this, Oracle puts a **value** of the parameter into the string. So, if the parameter has value `123`, your query in `q` variable will be:

```
... and nvl(123, ifl.id) = ifl.id
```

If the value will be `NULL`, the query will be:

```
... and nvl(, ifl.id) = ifl.id
```

I think it is what really happened. I suppose you need to write as follows:

```
q:= q || ' and nvl(:P53_INS_FIELD, ifl.id) = ifl.id';
```

Comment: You right. But if :P53_INS_FIELD don't select by user , I don't want to add this to where clause in query.

Comment: In this case I don't understand where you use your query in `q`. Is it a report, where the source has type "PL/SQL body, returning an SQL query"?

Comment: q is a query string in PL/SQL. End of it I run my sql. I have an interactive report with this PL/SQL